# What does Cirno's house look like?

Tags: touhou-great-fairy-wars

Recently I started playing Touhou 12.8, *(Great) Fairy Wars ~ Eastern Three Fairies*. It revolves around Cirno's revenge for destroying her house, but I couldn't find any reference to what her house actually looked like.

I haven't played all of the Touhou games (there's 20+ of them), and haven't read any of the art books, manga works, nor any interviews with ZUN, so if there's any canonical information, scenes or pictures about this, I'd love to know.

I'm really curious about how and where our "Beloved Tomboyish Girl" lived.

Comment: In one of the official printed work about the 3 mischievious fairies, we can see Cirno eating inside a tree trunk, similar to the 3 fairies' house except mostly empty. Whether it's her house before or after T12.8 I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Lol, I also wonders why Cirno was so angry. I remembered having a quick look in [Perfect Memento in Strict Sense](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Perfect_Memento_in_Strict_Sense/Cirno). If you are a "canon-strict" person, Perfect Memento is not illustrated by ZUN but text is 100% ZUN's. I consider it 100% canon.

In Perfect Memento, a reporter (forgotten her name, is it Aya ?) made interviews to different person in Gensokyo like in Bohemian Archive in Japanese Red.

But at her, she kept the mystery...Clever Cirno :)

Comment: It was Akuu. (and she never interviewed anyone.)